# Tensorflow error: An initializer for variable dense_1/kernel of dtype: 'complex64' is required

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting the following error when the code comes to the dense layer -> second line (`y_est =`...)

> Tensorflow error:  An initializer for variable dense_1/kernel of dtype:'complex64' is required

My variable `y_in` has a complex value and it seems I have to initialize my dense layer with the same variable type (complex64) but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?

```python
y_in = tf.reshape(input, shape=[-1,self.n])
y_est = tf.layers.dense(y_in, 20, activation= tf.nn.tanh) # line with error
h_hat = tf.layers.dense(y_est, 2, activation= None)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified your own custom [`kernel_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense), and the standard initializers in TensorFlow do not support complex weights yet. See [this ticket](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17097) for the details and possible solutions.